# Component Object Model - interface browser / explorer

Tags: windows, com

I have no idea what COM is, just only need to use few methods via COM.
But is there any COM browser that will show methods inside gicen interface? By name or GUID or something.
Does COM stores soem metadata like comments to interfaces etc?

Comment: Probably OLE Viewer from VS tools helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces defined in a type library (.tlb file, which can be embedded in a DLL) are described in it (the OLE/COM object viewer can show them), but hardly documented in it.

Others are only defined in the Windows headers (or in a third-party library's headers). To view the actual documentation, the best is to look it up on MSDN (or just Google the interface name, which works most of the time).